# Targeting specific pages with WordPress action hooks

Tags: wordpress, hook

I know you can use `is_front_page()` to determine if you're working on the front page of the site, so your action hook function could only add content if this was the front page, for example.  But how can you filter for other pages?  What if you only wanted to add content to the About_Us page, for example?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use is_page () conditional tags for specific page

```
Example : is_page( 'about-us' )
```

where about-us is the slug of your page .

For more details please refer below link
https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page